# Store a list of TypeFace objects in a Room Database

Tags: android, serialization, android-room

I'm implementing an app, which requests all GoogleFonts (API: https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=).

Therefore I'm using `FontsContractCompat.FontRequestCallback` to retrieve objects of type `TypeFace`. Each retrieved typeface is added to a `List<TypeFace>`.

Now I want to store this list into a Room Database. I thought that it is enough to serialize the TypeFace-Object into a string and then store it in the database.

The problem is, that when I load the serialized string and try to deserialize i back to a TypeFace-object, the app crashes.

```
Typeface typeface = new Gson().fromJson(item.getTypefaceString(), Typeface.class);
mTextName.setTypeface(typeface); // <-- Here it crashes
```

Is there any solution to store TypeFace-objects in a Room Database?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Hi Chris, can you include the crash (stacktrace) here? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverters ?

Comment: My understanding is you can't serialise Typeface

Answer (score 0):

The error in logcat is:

```
 9057-9057  libc                    cprojects.fontviewer                 A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x71c45398a0 in tid 9057 (ects.fontviewer)
 9083-9083  DEBUG                   pid-9083                             A  pid: 9057, tid: 9057, name: ects.fontviewer  >>> cprojects.fontviewer <<<
```

A serialized TypeFace-object looks like this:

```
 {"isLikeDefault":false,"mStyle":0,"native_instance":488625117344}
```

I think, it is true that a TypeFace-object can't be serialized and then deserialized back again.

I need to find a way to persist the list of TypeFaces in my app. Otherwise every time the app is opened, all fonts have be requested from Google's font Api. There are round about 1500 fonts, so this process tooks its time.